# How to count the number of words from a list from a text extract in a pdf using Python?

Tags: python, pdf, count, pdfplumber

I am trying to count a serie of words extract from a PDF but I get only 0 and it is not correct.

```
total_number_of_keywords = 0
pdf_file = "CapitalCorp.pdf"
tables=[]

words = ['blank','warrant ','offering','combination ','SPAC','founders']
count={} # is a dictionary data structure in Python


with pdfplumber.open(pdf_file) as pdf:
    pages = pdf.pages
    for i,pg in enumerate(pages):
        tbl = pages[i].extract_tables()
        for elem in words:
            count[elem] = 0
        for line in f'{i} --- {tbl}' :
            elements = line.split()
            for word in words:
                count[word] = count[word]+elements.count(word)
print (count)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
import pdfplumber
pdf_file = "CapitalCorp.pdf"
words = ['blank','warrant ','offering','combination ','SPAC','founders']

# Get text
text = ''
with pdfplumber.open(pdf_file) as pdf:
    for i, page in enumerate(pdf.pages):
        text = text+'\n'+str(page.extract_text())

# Setup count dictionary
count = {}
for elem in words:
    count[elem] = 0
        
# Count occurences
for i, el in enumerate(words):
    count[f'{words[i]}'] = text.count(el)
```

First, you store the content of PDF in the variable `text`, which is a string.

Then, you setup the `count` dictionary, with one key fo every element of `words` and respective values to 0.

Last, you count the occurrences of every element of `words` in `text` with the `count()` method and store it in the respective key of your `count` dictionary.

Comment: Thank you :) this code is working but I am missing some words. For example I am suppose to find 281 time "warrant" in the pdf file but with your code I find it only 65 times.

Comment: Can you share the PDF? I made an edit removign the lower() method: try that now

Comment: I have download the pdf from here: https://sec.report/Document/0001144204-14-043307/v383897_424b4.htm

Comment: when I remove lower() I miss a few more arguments

Comment: I will look into that later, but be careful to whitespaces and capital letters, the problem is probably some detail about that

Comment: Yes the problem was due to blank space! Thank you very much for your help!